# Java how to use Jackson ObjectMapper to concatenate two fields in Item class during serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class:

```
public class Item {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

When I convert it to JSON, I would like to combine the firstName and lastName fields. So something like:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = createMapper();
Item item = new Item("Bob", "Smith", 190);
String json = objMapper.writeValueAsString(item);
```

But I would like the json to look as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob Smith",
    "age" : "190"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "age" : "190"
}
```

Like wise, I would like to go the other way around. So if String anotherString is,

```
{
    "Name": "Jon Guy",
    "age" : "20"
}

objMapper.readValue(anotherString, Item);
```

should produce an Item with firstname = Jon, lastName = Guy, age = 20

Comment: Dont concat that values at all. Write a new get method: public getName(){ return firstName+" "+lastName);}

Comment: Will this still work for the reverse process where I turn a JSON to an Item object? Can I convert the JSON field "Name" to "firstName" and "lastName"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general heads up, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations are going to tell you what annotations will help you with jackson stuff.

Anyway, two things are happening here:

- You want to serialize an additional field
- You want to parse that additional field out from your object (I'll actually caution against this below)

I'm assuming you want to store the name field together, possibly for display purposes.

Given my experience I'm going to caution you against actually parsing the fullName property out of any incoming JSON, because it's actually non trivial (for example, imagine a person named Lauren de Silva).

The solution I'm going to present is going to serialize the object with a name property, but will ignore that property when the object is read back in.

What we're going to do is customize your POJO, rather than doing any special serialization code:

```
public class Item {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int age;

  @JsonProperty("Name",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
  public String getName() {
    return(firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
}
```

I would of course recommend adding null checking to the various methods if your firstName or lastName could be blank or null.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think you're right about the deserialization, I'm going to avoid doing that. For the serialization, we are actually writing the JSON to a database afterwards. We are going to use "Name" as the hash key of the database. My team insists on not touching the Item class, and changing the serialization instead so that the hash key can be modified easily in the future (by changing the serialization instead of the Item class). Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is, you are going to need to create a custom serializer.  If you want to create a custom ticket I will cover that one too.

Comment: If it's not too late, I would like to take you up on that offer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231692/custom-serializer-and-deserializer-to-concatenate-two-fields-during-serializatio

Comment: I am using the gson ,and done the same ,but during the serialization its not coming