# Custom serializer and deserializer to concatenate two fields during serialization/deserialization Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class:

```
public class Item {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

When I convert it to JSON, I would like to combine the firstName and lastName fields. So something like:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = createMapper();
Item item = new Item("Bob", "Smith", 190);
String json = objMapper.writeValueAsString(item);
```

But I would like the json to look as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob Smith",
    "age" : "190"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "age" : "190"
}
```

Like wise, I would like to go the other way around. So if String anotherString is,

```
{
    "Name": "Jon Guy",
    "age" : "20"
}

objMapper.readValue(anotherString, Item);
```

should produce an Item with firstname = Jon, lastName = Guy, age = 20

In summary during Serialization:
firstName and lastName are removed, Name is added.
During Deserialization:
Name is removed, firstName and lastName are restored to the object.

I've heard some solutions where we annotate the Item class. However, I would like to avoid doing this. Instead, I would like all of the code to be added via a custom serializer/deserializer.