# Polymorphic String Deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson-databind

I am using java w/ Jackson and would like to use a string prefix as my type for deserialization and the java pojo for generating that prefix at serialization.

```
class A implements TopLevel {
  String id;

  public String getPrefix() {
    return "aPrefix"
  }
}

class B implements TopLevel {
  String id;
  public String getPrefix() {
    return "bPrefix"
  }
}

interface TopLevel {
  String getPrefix()
}

//This should create an instance of A w/ Id = "423412421421412RandomId"
mapper.readValue("aPrefix.423412421421412RandomId", TopLevel.class)

//This should create an instance of A w/ Id = "OtherRandomId"
B b = mapper.readValue("bPrefix.OtherRandomId", TopLevel.class)

//This should create string "bPrefix.OtherRandomId"
mapper.writeValue(b)
```

Ideally I would like to be able to define the following, and use @JsonSubTypes or the most standard Jackson way possible to be able to create these value type strings.

Comment: What does this have to do with polymorphic deserialization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java how to use Jackson ObjectMapper to concatenate two fields in Item class during serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38084705/1553851)

Comment: Not exactly a dup of the other. His intent was to parse data and create new fields. My goal is to allow identifiers pojo type to be driven based on there id prefix when in string form. 

"<prefix>.<value>" should always map to the java pojo type mapped to that prefix containing that value.

Comment: I think I get it now. Sounds difficult though. You'll probably need a custom deserializer or something.

Comment: Why do you need Jackson for that?